# how to use onclick methods on android

Tags: android, class, button

So I have these five buttons that I want to be always present in all activities, sort of shortcut buttons to other activities. So i created a separate xml layout for this and just included them in the other activity layouts. I also created a class with corresponding methods that will handle the button clicks.

Now my problem is that I don't know how to use/declare this class in my activities. When I try to run my app, logcat gives me an error that it couldn't find the method handling the click.

How can I do that?

Here's my buttons handler class:

```
package com.meralco.pms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ButtonsHandler extends Activity{

protected void startSin() {
    Intent launch = new Intent(this, SinActivity.class);
    startActivity(launch);
}
protected void startCity() {
    Intent launch = new Intent(this, CityActivity.class);
    startActivity(launch);
}

protected void startHelp() {
    Intent launch = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
    startActivity(launch);

}
protected void startAll() {
    Intent launch = new Intent(this, AllActivity.class);
    startActivity(launch);

}
protected void startDate() {
    Intent launch = new Intent(this, DateActivity.class);
    startActivity(launch);

}
public void buttonClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
      {
      case R.id.button_sin:
          Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "SIN" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          startSin();
          break;
      case R.id.button_city:
          startCity();
          Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "CITY" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          break;
      case R.id.button_date:
          startDate();
          Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "DATE" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          break;
      case R.id.button_all:
          startAll();
          Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "ALL" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          break;
      case R.id.button_help:
          startHelp();
          Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "HELP" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          break;
      }
}
}
```

I think I am missing constructors. Am I heading the right way or I got it totally wrong? TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your ButtonsHandler to extend `Fragment` instead of Activity. Then you can include this fragment in all the rest of your activities.  They will have to extend `FragmentActivity` in order to host your ButtonsHandler fragment and the layout files will reference `com.meralco.pms.ButtonsHandler` as a fragment.

In order to support fragments in Android versions before 3.0, you'll want to use the Android Compatibility Library: http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

You'll also want to read up about Fragments: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

They are the recommended way for Android applications to re-use UI components like in this case:

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

With regards to your buttons, you'll want to hook up listeners like so:

```
Button helpButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_help);
helpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startHelp();
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "HELP" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                   
    }
});
```

Comment: Where will I put the listeners? In the `ButtonsHandler` class?  
I'll read about fragments. Thank you @louielouie :)

Comment: You're welcome. :)  Yes, if you make ButtonsHandler extend Fragment, then you would inflate the XML layout in `onCreateView()` and then hook up the listeners in `onActivityCreated()`.

Comment: okay.... hmmm... will try it out! haven't used on `onActivityCreated()` though. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to add OnClickListeners to register when the button is clicked.

You can find out how to use them on [Android Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) if you scroll down a little.

Answer (score 0):

In the xml of each button, make sure you have the property android:onClick="buttonClick"